# Python bot, trying to scan for specific standalone words

Tags: python, bots

I'm creating a reddit bot that searches for a specific word in comments. Lets say i scan for the word "america", i only want it to find america as a standalone word (I'm not sure what the word for this is). If someone says "american" i want the bot to ignore it.

```
words_to_match = ['america']

for comment in comments:
    comment_text = comment.body.lower()
    isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in words_to_match)
```

This is what i have so far.

EDIT: Actually, i just realized i could just make a new list of words to ignore, at least for this specific bot.

```
words_to_ignore = ['american']
```

Comment: do `string == comment_text' instead. unless comment_text is a string of multiple words. in that case, make your string have a space on both sides

Comment: So if a comment says *"I love America! I'm proud to be an American!"* you **don't** want it to match?

Comment: You could use a regular expression. re.search(r'\bamerica\b', comment_text)

Comment: do you want to find only america, but not american is that correct?

Comment: For specifying the word America, you could make it look for `america` in any arrangement of capitalization, and have it so it ignores the word if it is followed by or begun with any letter - I say letter because `america` could be `?america?` and you'd want that. I'm not very fluent in Python so I am not able to contribute code, sadly.

Comment: @LetzerWille yeah, since i'm only looking for one word, do you think just making a list of words such as 'american' and changing "if isMatch:" to "if comment_text not in words_to_ignore and isMatch:" would fix it?

Comment: I have changed the code into a function. So it will test if a standalone word 'America' regardless of case, appears in the text. You can then tailor your actions according to the output of the function. Just run the function against some of your sample texts and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You  want search just for that word you can use re.findall()

```
data = '''
I'm creating a reddit bot that searches for a specific word in comments.
Lets say i scan for the word "america", i only want it to find america as
 a standalone word (I'm not sure what the word for this is). If someone says
  "american" i want the bot to ignore it.
  '''
def is_match(st):
   # checks if word America, regardless of case, appears in
   # text as a standalone word
   import re
   if re.findall(r'\bamerica\b', st, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
     return True
  else:
     return False

  print(is_match(data))

  True
```

Comment: From what I understand of the OP's question, this is incorrect. The text contains the word `american`, so it shouldn't be a positive match...

Comment: @MattDMo \b is a word boundary that is why american is not in the list.

Comment: I know that. But the OP **doesn't** want it to match if a word like `american` is present.

Comment: @MattDMo, what do you think OP wants to match? OP wrote - 'i only want it to find america as a standalone word ' .....

Comment: The last sentence before the code block: *If someone says "american" i want the bot to ignore it.*

Comment: @MattDMo OP wants to ignore 'american'? 'american' gets ignored by findall. let's wait I have asked OP directly.